# Controlling audio with jQuery UI and jPlayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, audio, jplayer

I'm using the [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org) plugin along with jQuery UI's [slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/) widget. Everything seems to be setup but I seem to be experiencing some trouble when it comes to dragging the volume up and down. Dragging either way makes the volume jump too far up/down. The functionality is controlled through the `slide` property, I'm just not sure how to get it to drag accordingly.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9co0ac65/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :**

Since you have `position: absolute` for `jp-volume-bar-knob`, the `ui-slider-horizontal` bar lost its width (the horizontal bar over which the slider slides).

**Option 1:**

Instead of applying slider to `jp-volume-bar-knob` try applying it to `jp-volume-bar` it seems to be working fine then.

Here is the updated demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/9co0ac65/2/**

However, the initial volume level and initial slider value have to be set.

---

**Option 2:**

You can set the following css and still apply slider to `jp-volume-bar-knob`

```
.ui-slider-horizontal{
    height: 0;
    border: transparent;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/9co0ac65/3/**

---

## Update

Try something like this

- In this the volume bar works fine.
- Default value is replicated on the slider.

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var myPlayer = $("#jquery_jplayer_1"),
        options = {
            ready: function (event) {
                if (event.jPlayer.status.noVolume) {
                    // if there is no volume add custom styling
                }
                // Setup the player with media.
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    title: "Bubble",
                    m4a: "http://jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-07-Bubble.mp3",
                    oga: "http://jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg"
                });
            },
            volumechange: function (event) {
                if (event.jPlayer.options.muted) {
                    myControl.volume.slider("value", 0);
                } else {
                    myControl.volume.slider("value", event.jPlayer.options.volume);
                }
            },
            swfPath: "http://jplayer.org/latest/dist/jplayer",
            supplied: "mp3, oga",
            wmode: "window",
            useStateClassSkin: true,
            autoBlur: false,
            smoothPlayBar: true,
            keyEnabled: true,
            remainingDuration: true,
            toggleDuration: true
        },
        myControl = {
            volume: $(".jp-volume-bar-knob")
        };

    // Instance jPlayer
    myPlayer.jPlayer(options);

    myControl.volume.slider({
        animate: "fast",
        max: 1,
        range: "min",
        step: 0.01,
        value: $.jPlayer.prototype.options.volume,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            myPlayer.jPlayer("option", "muted", false);
            myPlayer.jPlayer("option", "volume", ui.value);
        }
    });
});
```

I adopted this from [jplayer demo](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-07/) and modified a bit based on the question.

Here is the updated demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/9co0ac65/6/**

---

## update 2

Change the volume bar markup to something like this

```
<div class="jp-volume-bar"></div>
```

Instead of changing all the `.jp-*'s` css, change `jquery-ui's` css to something like this

```
.ui-slider-horizontal{
    background: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 4px;
    width: 100px;
}
.ui-slider-range{
    background: #cc181e;
}
```

Here is the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/9co0ac65/10/**

Comment: Wow thank you! Do you happen to know what's causing the knob to shift down the way it has due to the change? I tried altering the css itself but had no luck.

Comment: @CarlEdwards: updated my answer, please check it now

Comment: Noticed a small bug with option 2. The knob starts at zero but once you start to drag it catches up to the the current volume. It doesn't lead to the very front of the current volume bar either. Is this because the initial volume level and slider value isn't set as you mentioned?

Comment: as far as I can observe, it looks like the `ui-slider-horizontal` and red slider do not have the same width. Let me look at it again.

Comment: The only thing strange is that on load the knob starts behind the current volume. Do you also see this?

Comment: @CarlEdwards: Updated the answer again. Please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76829/discussion-between-carl-edwards-and-dhiraj-bodicherla).

Comment: The latest fiddle's volume knob seems to jump. I explained it more in detail in the chat.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for looking into the issue.